# How to put an int[50] inside an int[100]?

Tags: c

Is there a way to put an array inside another array without using loops? This loop feels a bit weird:

```
uint8_t buf0[50];
populate_buf( buf0 );
uint8_t buf1[100];
buf1[0] = 'S';
for ( uint8_t i = 0; i < 50; i++ )
    buf1[1+i] = buf0[i];
```

Comment: [memcpy](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/cstring/memcpy/)?

Comment: In this case, why you're copying *at all* seems overkill. `buf1[0] = 'S'; populate_buf(buf1+1);`

Comment: @WhozCraig populate_buf is expensive. buf0 and buf1 are modified and used differently.

Comment: Adding to @Alexander , `memcpy` is much efficient tool for copy requirements like this

Comment: Not in this code, thus my response.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

```
memcpy(&buf1[1], &buf0[0], sizeof buf0);
```

Comment: +1 (and if I could upvote again, I would). Most remotely reasonable compilers have intrinsics for this on a per-platform implementation. You would be hard-pressed to beat it.

Comment: Note that this will probably not work if the types are different - e.g. you cannot copy an array of `int`s into a `long` array safely.

Answer (score 0):

To avoid copying you could initially allocate N elements dynamically and `realloc` to 2N. If you have to add a front element anyway, a ring/circular buffer implementation could be useful to get away with copy.